# Linux. Как исправить ошибки поврежденной файловой системы во время загрузки HDD?

Tags: linux, hdd

На внешнем HDD размером 500ГБ имеется xubuntu.

Загрузка в систему осуществлялась "как с флешки" хорошо и достаточно долго.

На днях винт по ошибке отключили от сети во время работы и с тех пор он не загружается.

Проверку на crypto вход выполняет на ура и на этом всё, дальше ни окна выбора пользователей, ничего.

Пробовал и так и эдак. Наконец выдал вот что
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А следом при следующей перезагрузке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда попытался войти с безопасным режимом, выдал другую картину, где пишет что ядро паникует (Kernel panic)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У кого у кого, а паника сейчас не у ядра.

Пробовал писать команды [по совету](https://losst.ru/proverka-diska-na-bitye-sektory-v-linux) но не помогло

Будьте добры, подскажите, что же тут делать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На этапе (initramfs) выполни команду `e2fsck -f /dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root`

Это проверка Вашего корневого раздела. При повреждении суперблоков и отсутствии журнала можно потерять часть файлов. ОС простит выполнить эту проверку вручную, чтоб пользователь видел что может потерять.

В ней много соглашайся.

Там вопросы вроде: файл без имени номер 12345678 поврежден, удалить его? Эти файлы, точнее их обывки, можно будет потом посмотреть в папке lost+found.

После этого этого нажми ctrl+d. Если системные файлы не сильно повреждены - система загрузится, но возможно прийдется переустановить.

Comment: Только что ты спас целую историю! Спасибо :-)

Comment: @eri, в соседнем ответе совсем бред написан или нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy я не особо понял что Владимир имеет ввиду, но сбитые часики ни в суперблоке, ни в инодах не останавливали монтирование EXT по моему опыту. Надо провести эксперимент ;)

Comment: Если уж советуете соглашаться на всякие крякозяберные команды, то описывайте их смысл.

Comment: @user7860670 добавил) да не кракозябры, а вполне интуитивно понятная команда, если прочесть экран

Comment: [интуитивно понятная](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150310-00/?p=44503)

Comment: @user7860670 добавил ещё

Comment: @user7860670 99% пользователей не читают системные сообщения и нажимают первую кнопку. В этом я с вами согласен